# special characters using barcode scanner to integrate in java application

Tags: java, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a barcode Scanner and i want to integrate it on my JSF application, but unfortunetly when i scan a product I obtain a special chatacter in textfield like below :
-&çé'à'"àà'éç
-&çé'éçèàà&'"

Could you please help me ?

Comment: is your barcode scanner compatible with the barcode font used ?

Comment: how could i know that?

Comment: Does your barcode snanner reads 3of9, 128, etc..., and what is the barcode font you used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it with simply made a trancodification between azerty and qwerty

& becomes 1
é becomes 2
....
etc